# To find a short way to prove - if $p$ is a prime and $p|a^2+b^2, \space p|b^2+c^2$, then $p|a, p|b, p|a^2-c^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

To prove, if $p$ is a prime and $p|a^2+b^2, \space p|b^2+c^2$, then $p|a, p|b, p|a^2-c^2$.

$$p|a^2+b^2\\p|b^2+c^2\\ \therefore p|a^2+b^2+b^2+c^2\space\space \text {i.e.}\space \space p|a^2+2b^2+c^2 \space \text {or}\\ p|a^2+b^2-b^2-c^2,\space\space \text {i.e.}\space \space p|a^2-c^2\\ \therefore p|(a+c)\space\space \text {or}\space\space p|(a-c)\\ \Rightarrow p|a+c+a-c \space\space \text {i.e.}\space \space p|2a \space\space \text {i.e.}\space \space p|2 \space\space \text{or} \space \space p|a \\ \text{Similarly}\space\space p|a+c-a+c, \therefore p|2 \space \space \text{or}\space\space p|c\\ \space\\\text{Since},\space \space p|a,\space\\\text{then},p|a^2 \space \space  \space\\\text{and},\space \space p|a^2+b^2\\ \space \\\text{Hence}\space\space p|b^2, ( \because p \space\space\text {is  prime}\space),\\ \therefore p|b  $$..

Does it correctly complete the proof? Or if possible kindly provide a alternative short way  to prove. Any suggestion is precious and appreciated.

Comment: $p\mid a+c$ OR $p\mid a-c$ doesn't mean $p$ divides a combination of both. Indeed, $5\mid 10$ or $5\mid 6$; but surely we cannot conclude $5\mid 10+6$.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @vrugtehagel But $5\nmid 6$ does it? Let $5\mid 15$ instead, then does $5\mid 10 + 15$ or not? If $p\mid a+c$ then for some number $x$, we have $px = a + c$ or $a\equiv -c \pmod {px}$, so...

Comment: @user477343 no, $5$ indeed does not divide $6$, but it does divide either $10$ or $6$. My point is, if we have a statement $A$ and $B$, and we know $A$ or $B$ is true, we cannot use both to get to a conclusion as one of them may be false.

Comment: @vrugtehagel ahhhhh, I see what you mean, now. Sorry. (Bad understanding of english)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite easy to see your theorem isn't true. Take $a=c$, and it reduces to

> If $p\mid a^2+b^2$, then $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$.

This obviously isn't true, take for example $p=5$, $a=2$ and $b=1$ (and those translate to $(a,b,c,p)=(2,1,2,5)$).

Comment: But if I say that $\space p|a^2+b^2, \space p|b^2+c^2$, so, $p$ divides $a^2-c^2$. Then I think the statement should be correct and my attempts too..And thank you for pointing the error. (+1)

Comment: Well, if $a=c$ then $p\mid a^2-c^2$ is always true because $a^2-c^2=0$. But yes, your proof that $p\mid a^2-c^2$ is correct.